# Map CSV columns to a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've seen quite some examples on how to import CSV using FasterCSV, SmarterCSV or the default CSV library. All those examples assume that the csv is in a certain format though.

I would have a fixed model containing address fields (street, hsno, city, etc) but I have no control over the data that is being uploaded.

I'm looking for a way to map the CSV data (by header names) to my model before the data is loaded in the model.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you would be better to give a template of the CSV. If you don't set a "standard" between your code and the user's input, it can be very hard to map what the user sent and what you have in you app. Some users would have a field 'first_name' and 'last_name' when others would just have 'full_name'. Provide a CSV template with pre-filled data (or just the column names) is a better idea I think

Comment: I'm with @MrYoshiji on this one. You are descending into a pit of madness. Many users, even when given an explicit CSV format, manage to screw it up. Making this open-ended is going to expose your code to all manners of insane variations that you'll be chasing down until the end of time. You can certainly add code that tries to guess (at varying levels of sophistication) what the data is, but you you still need to account for formats that are unguessable.

Comment: I agreet that it is messy, but I feel it's nicer for an end customer to be able to just upload a file, instead of making sure that the format fits what I dictate. I was indeed planning on having combo boxes with my model's field names in, and give the user the ability to map their headers to my model fields. The difficulty lies in having to read the uploaded file first so that I can catch the headers. The only possibility I see right now is to use javascript to read the first few lines and take it from there. That would remove the possibility to use a gem like Roo in order to upload xls files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can create a combo box with the model attributes and let the user choose which attributes a column should match.

Take a look at [MailChimp import](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-create-and-import-my-list) at the section "Mapping Fields" for an visual example.

(Sorry for the advertising, but this is the one example i can remember)